# Mac OS X Remote Installation on Macbook Pro

Tags: networking, mac-osx, mac

Similar to the way Apple has enabled remote OS X Install using a different computers drive for the Macbook Air, I need to enable it on my Macbook Pro.  When holding down the option key and booting into the selection menu, there is no option to connect to a network (via the dropdown like the Macbook Air).  Does anyone know the terminal command to enable this sort of behavior?  I already have the commands to enable remote disc on a macbook pro, which are here (from terminal):

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool true

defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser ODSSupported -bool true
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with a stock MacBook Pro. Booting from Remote Disc is something provided by the firmware of the MacBook Air, and I don't think its present on on other models. The terminal commands you listed above allow the installed operating system to browse and view Remote Disc servers; they have nothing to do with the firmware.

I think all current Macs support NetBoot/NetInstall, so if you had an OS X Server handy you could install that way. I don't know if there are any free implementations of NetInstall. Otherwise, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2129) for precise details.

My understanding is that both computers (it can be a Mac or PC providing the DVD drive) need to be on the same subnet as the avalibility of the DVD drive is advertised either using Bonjour or some other broadcast method.

Essentially you don't specify a network address it simply searches for the broadcasts from the computer providing the DVD drive.

Comment: Well to this extent, this is part of it.  There are several parts.  First was doing this, second is getting Macbook Pro to see the remote drive (using the terminal commands above).  The last step (one I need) is actually enabling me to connect to a network (holding option at boot).  There is a dropdown on the macbook air, that is not on the macbbook pro.  I need this dropdown which I am assuming is an option to run from the terminal similar to above commands.  Just can't find it.